# SQL : Getting duplicate rows along with other variables

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am working on Terradata SQL. I would like to get the duplicate fields with their count and other variables as well. I can only find ways to get the count, but not exactly the variables as well.

Available input

```
   +---------+----------+----------------------+
    | id      | name     |      Date       |
    +---------+----------+----------------------+
    | 1       | abc      |         21.03.2015   |
    | 1       | def      |          22.04.2015  |
    | 2       | ajk      |          22.03.2015  |
    | 3       | ghi      |          23.03.2015  |
    | 3       | ghi      |          23.03.2015  |
```

Expected output :

```
    +---------+----------+----------------------+
    | id     | name     |      count            | // Other fields
    +---------+----------+----------------------+
    | 1       | abc      |            2         |
    | 1       | def      |            2         |
    | 2       | ajk      |            1         |
    | 3       | ghi      |            2         |
    | 3       | ghi      |            2         |
```

What am I looking for :

**I am looking for all duplicate rows, where duplication is decided by ID and to retrieve the duplicate rows as well.**

All I have till now is :

```
SELECT
    id, name, other-variables, COUNT(*)
FROM
    Table_NAME
GROUP BY
    id, name
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This is not showing correct data. Thank you.

Comment: Your expected outcome doesn't match the columns that you're selecting in your attempt at all. Please provide what you're actually trying to get.

Comment: If you have the query that counts the duplicates without the extra attributes, you put it in a subquery and join that to the outer query which can also pick up the extra attributes required.

Comment: @TomH : Sorry, I had previously just pasted the query I found in the link, modified the query. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @We are Borg As you are using Count(*),so its compulsory to know about "Other variables".please provide detailed query.

Comment: @HoneyBadger : Didn't understood what you said, also I have edited the post as per Tom's suggestion. Please check how the query looks now. :-)

Comment: You need other-variables in group by.

Comment: @SagarR : It's not hard and fast to user Count(*), I just want all duplicate rows, where duplication is decided by ID. I have edited my main post. PLease check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [window aggregate function](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_109A/ch09.13.039.html), like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT id, name, other-variables,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS duplicates
        FROM   users
       ) AS sub
WHERE  duplicates > 1
```

Using a teradata extension to ISO SQL syntax, you can simplify the above to:

```
SELECT  id, name, other-variables,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS duplicates
FROM    users
QUALIFY duplicates > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this one seems to be working. The only thing is, the name is encrypted, for that we use a function, like select id, decrypt_funct(name),other variables. When I do this, it's not working. Error : All expressions in a derived table must have an explicit name. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Just add an alias after the computed column: `decrypt_funct(name) as mycol`

Comment: well I just added decrypt_funct(name) as "mm" and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Haha, I just did that.. Thanks my friend.. :-)

Comment: Instead of a Derived Table plus WHERE you can simply use a Teradata SQL extension, `QUALIFY duplicates > 1`

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. Added that.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the accepted and perfectly correct answer, you can use:

```
SELECT          {all your required 'variables' (they are not variables, but attributes)}
,               cnt.Count_Dups
FROM            Table_NAME TN
INNER JOIN      (
                     SELECT  id
                     ,       COUNT(1) Count_Dups
                     GROUP BY id
                     HAVING   COUNT(1) > 1 -- If you want only duplicates
                ) cnt
           ON   cnt.id = TN.id
```

**edit**: According to your edit, duplicates are on `id` only. Edited my query accordingly.

Comment: SQL Server is not involved in this question. See the tag `teradata`.

Comment: @trincot, edited answer. I don't know teradata at all, but this should still work, I would think

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT
    id, COUNT(id)
FROM
    Table_NAME
GROUP BY
    id
HAVING 
    COUNT(id) > 1
```

Comment: You have not show the name. The excepted result has 3 columns

Comment: Rather than just pasting a random bunch of code, explain what you did and why. That way, the OP and any future readers with the same problem can actually learn something from your answer, rather than just copy/pasting it and asking the same question again tomorrow.